# How do I bind a property to my xaml that I manipulate before setting the property?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have this method:

```
private async Task DisplayVideos(string query)
        {
            var videoObj = await _mediaService.GetVideos(query);
            Videos = videoObj.Hits;
            var size = "640x360";
            var picIdList = videoObj.Hits.Select(x=>x.Picture_id).ToList();

            foreach (var pic in picIdList)
            {
                PictureId = $"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{pic}_{size}.jpg";
            }
        }
```

This method hits an api endpoint and gets back a video object. I want to get the picture_id from the video object and manually set a size, then input the parameters into a specific url and then set the binding context of my image in my xaml to that specific url as I'm doing above.

However, the issue above is I'm setting PictureId to the last url in that list. How can I fix it so that a list of picture ids and in my listview, I have a image bind for every cell. I'm using FlowListView layout.

Here's my xaml:

```
<flv:FlowListView FlowColumnCount="2" SeparatorVisibility="None" HasUnevenRows="true"
            FlowItemTappedCommand="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" 
            FlowItemsSource="{Binding Videos}" >

        <flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Aspect="AspectFill" HeightRequest="200" Source="{Binding PictureId}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </flv:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>

    </flv:FlowListView>
```

Comment: shouldn't PictureId be a property on each object in your Videos list?

Comment: @Jason yes normally however oddly pixabay api has it so I picture_id in the video object is just an id number but to get the preview image for the video, I need to set the picture_id and the size and set it inside the url to get back the preview image I want. Here's the docs if you're curious: https://pixabay.com/api/docs/

Comment: You should be able to extend their class to add your own property to it that returns the appropriate url

Comment: @Jason How? Can you elaborate on what you mean? Thanks!

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that `GetVideos`() returns a `List<Video>`, and that `Video` is a class that you've defined in your code, so you can modify it.

Just add a read-only Property to the Video class that will return the url for the image

```
public string PictureUrl {
  get {
    $"https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/{Picture_Id}_640x360.jpg";
  }
}
```